# Registering a custom controller class in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have this this class that is a ServiceProvider

```
namespace Package\Avatar;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class AvatarServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Bootstrap the application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        include __DIR__.'/routes.php';
    }

    /**
     * Register the application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        try{
            $this->app->make('Package\Avatar\AvatarController');
        } catch (\Exception $e){
            dd($e);
        }

    }
}
```

But when I try to access to some url of AvatarCotroller class the screen is Blank, and no show neither error. But whenever I comment this line

```
$this->app->make('Package\Avatar\AvatarController');
```

I can get the normal errors of Laravel.

Comment: I don't know why you are trying to `resolve` a class right inside of the `register ` callback of your ServiceProvider, did you already `bind` that class on another file? something like:  `$this->app->bind('Package\Avatar\AvatarController',function(){ return new Package\Avatar\AvatarController() });`

Answer (score 0):

You can get rid of including the `routes.php` in the boot method of the service provider. Simply use `$this->app->call('Package\Avatar\AvatarController@method')` to call the method on the controller

Answer (score 0):

try

`php artisan optimize` : to reuse all frequently used classes php will make an cached class in cache/service.php. So we if add new service we need to run it. We need to use it whenever we add new dependency without using composer.

`php artisan cache:clear` : clear all the above cache and remap everything